# Debug assertion Failed error with vector array

Tags: c++

```
  vector<string> names;

    // Read names from file book.txt
    ifstream in("movie.txt");
    if (!in.is_open())
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";

    string word;
    while (getline(in, word))
        names.push_back(word);

    int pos(0), i(0), j(0);
    string temp;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {

        j = i;

        while (j >= 0 && names[j] < names[j - 1])
        {
            temp = names[j];
            names[j] = names[j - 1];
            names[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }

    }

    // Loop to print names
    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        cout << names[i] << '\n';
```

> Not sure where the error is coming from as it still runs, but as i try
>   and execute the file it says "Debug assertion error." Any help?

Comment: You reference `names[j - 1]` when `j = 0`.

Comment: Did you try attaching a debugger to your process, pressing "retry", and investigating the values of variables, at the point of failed assertion? The fact, that you get assertion failed on invalid operation of `std::vector`, leads me to believe, that you are using MSVS. It has excellent debugger.

Comment: Every time i try retry, i get "Vector subscript out of range."

Comment: @jbondy "_Every time i try retry, i get "Vector subscript out of range."_" Did you investigate the size of vector, and the subscript, you are trying to index the vector with, at the point of failed assertion? Chances are, that you... are indexing the `std::vector` out of range..

Comment: where is the type for vector names; ????

Comment: vector<string> names;
earlier in the code sorry

Comment: As @0x499602D2 said, `while (j >= 0 && names[j] < names[j - 1])` starts `j` at 0, so `names[j - 1]` is `names[-1]` to begin with, which is causing the problem. What did you mean?

Comment: @jbondy check the answer it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the names then try this it works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    vector<string> names;
    ifstream in("movies.txt");

    if (!in.is_open())
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";

    string word;
    while (getline(in, word))
        names.push_back(word);


    for (auto i : names)
        cout << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```